# Emulating print media in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, printing, internet-explorer-11, ie-developer-tools, print-preview

I am implementing printing of a web page that is originally displayed in Internet Explorer.

I would like to use the browser "Inspect Element" functionality when in print mode. So I would like to emulate print media, while still actually displaying the page in the browser.

[Google Chrome has exactly this functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540990/using-chromes-element-inspector-in-print-preview-mode).

Is this available in Internet Explorer. In particular, IE11?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I do not believe that IE11 currently supports the F12 developer tools in print preview.

I do not know whether such support is in the works, but you could consider adding a suggestion to IE platform [suggestion box](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2014/10/16/introducing-the-ie-platform-suggestion-box-on-uservoice.aspx) on UserVoice.

If you're looking to debug issues that only appear during printing, perhaps you could create a simpler case, add a DIV that displays debugging info, and then display your DIV using a [print media stylesheet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Printing).

Hope this helps...

Answer (score -16):

Yes, It is available in IE 11. Click Tools Button (Alt + X) and then Click Print>Print Preview

Comment: Print Preview does not do what I want. It is not possible to do "Inspect element" in the Print Preivew window.